# Angular Material: recalculate position of mat-menu on height change

Tags: angular, angular-material

Suppose I have a `mat-menu` that changes its `height` a few moments after it is opened (due to a data load). At first it has `50px` height and then it *might* have something like `200px`. If its trigger is in the bottom side of the window, it might happen that the panel opens to the bottom (as there is enough space for the initial `50px` height) but right after the load of the data it remains in the bottom side. I'd like to recalculate its position and act as if it had been closed and opened again (in that case the panel is opened above the trigger due to the lack of space in the bottom). Is there a way to do it?

You can test it in this simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lorwfh?file=app/menu-overview-example.ts

Comment: You can change the position on mat-menu using ngClass you add one class when data is loaded.

Comment: @upinderkumar Thanks, but I'd prefer a "native" Angular Material solution instead of adding "tricks"... There should be a way of telling Angular "please recalculate the position of the panel, because I know that its size changed", shouldn't there?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is not an exposed method yet to solve this problem, I have solved it by dispatching a resize event on purpose to force the menu to recalculate the position after new items are added/removed.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```